# How to incorporate tawk.to UI into a chat app?

Tags: android, chat, clone, whatsapp

I have been trying to build [a WhatsApp clone app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euwZQ.png), and I need to know if it is possible to incorporate `tawk.to UI` into a chat app.

There were guides and projects on GitHub and I managed to do one, but since I need a production app, I need something like **Stream chat**, however, it costs me more than I anticipated. Since `tawk.to` is free, I thought why not give it a try. But after all, I am totally new to all this and I would really like some advice.

Is it actually possible to use `tawk.to UI` for an app? If so what should I consider? What other resources do I need?